# How to add custom tab to My account(frontend)

Tags: magento-1.9

I need to add new tab in my custom module to frontend(my account)

-> this may be addLink or customer_account_navigation (its depend on the requirment)
            viewwedding_couplewedding_couple/customer/view/ZZZZZZZZ

```
<wedding_couple_customer> –> controller path
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <reference name="my.account.wrapper">
        <block type="wedding_couple/customer" name="wedding_couple_newtab_newtab" template="customer/newtab/newtab.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</wedding_couple_customer>
```

Answer (score 22):

Ensure you have also declared your layout file in `config.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    ...
    <frontend>
        ...
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <module>
                    <file>module.xml</file>
                </module>
            </updates>
        </layout>
        ...
    </frontend>
    ...
</config>
```

and then add the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    ...
    <customer_account>
        <reference name="customer_account_navigation">
            <action method="addLink">
                <name>unique_tab_name</name>
                <path>module/controller</path>
                <label>Your Tab Label</label>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </customer_account>
    ...
</layout>
```

Ensure you have declared your controller resource in you modules `config.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    ...
    <frontend>
        ...
        <routers>
            <module> <!-- this matches the first part of the layout handle
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Namespace_Module</module>
                    <frontName>module</frontName> <!-- this matches 'module' before the slash in the path node above -->
                </args>
            </module>
        </routers>
        ...
    </frontend>
    ...
</config>
```

Then in your controller action referenced by `module/controller` in the path node add the following to render the layout (but first redirect if the user is not logged in):

```
<?php
class Namespace_Module_ControllerController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{   
    public function indexAction()
    {
        if (!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()):
            $this->_redirect('customer/account/login');
            return;
        endif;

        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

Then in your layout file declare the content you want to load when clicking the tab (which will result in a request to the `Namespace_Module_ControllerController`):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <module_controller_index> <!-- module here matches node directly beneath <routers> in config.xml -->
       <update handle="customer_account"/> <!-- include existing customer account layout -->
       <reference name="my.account.wrapper"> <!-- target parent block -->
           <block type="module/block" name="unique_layout_name" template="module/template.phtml"/>
           <block type="customer/account_dashboard" name="customer.account.link.back" template="customer/account/link/back.phtml" /> <!-- add a back link -->
       </reference>
   </module_controller_index>
</layout>
```

Now in your block class add the following, you'll probably want to be able to pull the customer object hence adding the `getCustomer()` method:

```
<?php
class Namespace_Module_Block_Block extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    public function getCustomer()
    {
        $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
        if ($customer->getId()):
            return $customer;
        endif;

        return false;
    }
}
```

And finally in your template `module/template.phtml` output whatever you need to:

```
<div class="page-title">
    <h1><?php echo $this->__('My Tab') ?></h1>
</div>
<?php if ($customer = $this->getCustomer()): ?>
    <div>Hello <?php echo $customer->getName(); ?></div>
<?php else: ?>
    <div>No customer here</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Great, could you mark the answer as accepted in that case?

Answer (score 2):

You can add by using following set of xml

```
<customer_account>
    <reference name="customer_account_navigation">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>custom_menu</name><path>custommodule/controller</path><label>My Custom Menu</label></action>
    </reference>
</customer_account>
```

You will need to alter the name,path, label values accordingly.