# Create an adminhtml public page

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, adminhtml

I wish to create a simple **adminhtml public page** and not a private page.

> www.website.com/admin/users/form

How can I realize that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authentication is handled by `Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action::preDispatch()` function. If you don't call `parent::preDispatch()` you should be able enable access without authentication.

But is that really a good idea? Make sure you aren't exposing major security holes here.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, forms in the admin shouldn't be public since it uses authentication to prevent unauthorised access. Ideally, you want to create a module that extends the customer account section. This may help - [How to add custom tab to My account(frontend)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/48371/how-to-add-custom-tab-to-my-accountfrontend) .

Comment: Thanks for your help but your answer does not help me. My page must be public because I wish to create a login form for my users roles only.