# New custom tab is not displaying below My account

Tags: magento-1.9

I am trying to create new tab **"My Designs"**  below Customer Account section similar to **"My Product like"** I tried below code, but its not displaying new tab. Also followed [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/48371/how-to-add-custom-tab-to-my-accountfrontend/48388)

[image]

**config.xml**

```
  <layout>
      <updates>
        <design>
          <file>design.xml</file>
        </design>
      </updates>
    </layout>
```

**layout.xml**

```
<customer_account>
        <!-- Mage_Wishlist -->
      <reference name="customer_account_navigation">
          <action method="addLink" translate="label">
          <name>design</name>
          <path>Design/</path>
          <label>My Designs</label></action>
      </reference>
</customer_account>
```

**config.xml**

```
<routers>
      <design>
        <use>standard</use>
          <args>
            <module>Outthink_Design</module>
            <frontName>design</frontName>
          </args>
      </design>
    </routers>
```

Also we included `IndexController.php` in app/code/local/Namespace/module/controllers &

`productlike.phtml` in app/design/frontend/rwd/theme_name/template/design

Is there any way to debug or where i am missing ?

**Edit 2**

```
<design_index_index>   
      <update handle="customer_account"/>
      <reference name="my.account.wrapper">   
        <block type="design/index" name="design_index" template="design/design.phtml"> 
            <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
              <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager" />
          </block>         
                </block>  
      </reference>   
  </design_index_index>
```

**Edit 3**  - app/design/frontend/rwd/theme/layout/design.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>   
<layout version="0.1.0">   
   <default>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem">
                <type>skin_css</type>
                <name>css/design/ajaxlogin1/styles.css</name>
                <params/>
            </action>
            <action method="addItem">
                <type>skin_js</type>
                <name>js/design/ajaxlogin1/script.js</name>
            </action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="before_body_end">
            <block type="core/template" name="ajaxlogin">
                <action method="setTemplate"><template>design/index.phtml</template></action>
                <block type="customer/form_register" name="customer_form_register_ajax" template="design/register.phtml">
                    <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="customer.form.register.fields.before" as="form_fields_before" translate="label">
                        <label>Form Fields Before</label>
                    </block>
                </block>
                <block type="persistent/form_remember" name="persistent.remember.me" template="persistent/remember_me.phtml" />
                <block type="core/template" name="persistent.remember.me.tooltip" template="persistent/remember_me_tooltip.phtml" />
            </block>
        </reference>
    </default>


     <customer_account>
  <reference name="left">
      <action method="addLink" translate="label">
      <name>design</name>
      <path>Design/</path>
      <label>My Designs</label></action>
  </reference>
</customer_account>


  <design_index_index>   
      <update handle="customer_account"/>
      <reference name="my.account.wrapper">   
        <block type="design/index" name="design_index" template="design/design.phtml"> 
            <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
              <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager" />
          </block>         
                </block>  
      </reference>   
  </design_index_index>   
</layout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your code with this:

```
<customer_account>
            <!-- Mage_Wishlist -->
          <reference name="customer_account_navigation">
              <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer">
              <name>design</name>
              <path>design/index/index/</path>
              <label>My Designs</label></action>
          </reference>
</customer_account>
<design_index_index>
      <update handle="customer_account"/>
      <reference name="content">
                    <block type="design/index"  name="design_index"
                          template="template="design/design.phtml"" />
      </reference>        
  </design_index_index>
```

Please update it accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, updated your code, still new tab is not visible, also please check `Edit 2` part in question.....

Comment: Are you able to see  "My Designs" in navigation ?

Comment: No, i am not seeing in navigation also in [site](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/customer/account/login) , is there anything i am missing in template or controller or block code ?

Comment: Please share layout.xml full code because this code is running on magento 1.9.2

Comment: please check `edit3` part in question.....

Comment: I have updated my answer just replace that part and clear cache then check

Comment: updated code, still not visible.....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54862/discussion-between-baby-in-magento-and-arunendra).

Comment: Thanks a lot,  after i updated your code in local.xml , its displaying new tab, i am checking why the code is not working in layout.xml.....

Answer (score 2):

Try below code

```
<customer_account>
  <reference name="customer_account_navigation">
      <action method="addLink" translate="label">
      <name>design</name>
      <path>Design/</path>
      <label>My Designs</label></action>
  </reference>
</customer_account>
```

please check in your customer.xml file  links are in this block

```
<block type="customer/account_navigation" name="customer_account_navigation" before="-" template="customer/account/navigation.phtml">
```

if it is some other block then replace refrence name

Comment: Thanks, updated your code, cleared cache, logout and login, still `new tab` is not visible, is there anything i am missing in template or controller or block code ?

Comment: @BabyinMagento check updated code

Comment: in `customer/account/navigation.phtml` only 3 tabs code available,  please check customer.xml full code : http://pastebin.com/5mQkxiYj

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support, i got solution, i need your support like this in future also for my other questions.....